# Forming a sequence of actions from recurring events

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID          TARGET_ACTION              TARGET_DATE 
       
366                    0                21.04.2021      
186                    1                03.04.2021
929                    0                14.04.2021
366                    1                17.04.2021
```

Each ID in this table can be repeated and have a different `TARGET_ACTION` value for a different date. I want to form a sequence of actions for each id, dividing it into weeks so that it looks like this:

```
ID          01.04.2021-07.04.2021    08.04.2021-14.04.2021   15.04.2021-21.04.2021 
       
366                    0                       0                       1
186                    1                       1                       0
929                    0                       1                       0
```

How can I do that?

Comment: This is something you would rather do in your app, not in SQL. Just read the table data, loop through the result and add a new row to your grid for every new ID and add a new column for every new week.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pivoting in this case, though for the whole year there would be 52 week columns.
First, your sample data:

```sql
WITH
    a_table AS
        (
            Select 366  "ID",   0 "TARGET_ACTION",  To_Date('21.04.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "TARGET_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 186  "ID",   1 "TARGET_ACTION",  To_Date('03.04.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "TARGET_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 929  "ID",   0 "TARGET_ACTION",  To_Date('14.04.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "TARGET_DATE" From Dual Union All
            Select 366  "ID",   1 "TARGET_ACTION",  To_Date('17.04.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "TARGET_DATE" From DUAL
        ),
```

Next thing to do is to join your dataset with some kind of time dimension table. It is a very good thing to have for different uses. The link to how to create one is here: http://oracleolap.blogspot.com/2011/01/script-for-time-dimension-table.html
Instead, I've created a small cte just with weeks from the question:

```sql
  weeks AS
    (
        SELECT 14 "WEEK_NUM", To_Date('01.04.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "WEEK_STARTS", To_Date('07.04.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "WEEK_ENDS" From Dual Union All
        SELECT 15 "WEEK_NUM", To_Date('08.04.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "WEEK_STARTS", To_Date('14.04.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "WEEK_ENDS" From Dual Union All
        SELECT 16 "WEEK_NUM", To_Date('15.04.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "WEEK_STARTS", To_Date('21.04.2021', 'dd.mm.yyyy') "WEEK_ENDS" From Dual 
    )
```

Now, if you get the weeks from your data and join them with time dimension you could pivot the resulting dataset. Here is the mainSQL with the result.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    ID, W14, W15, W16
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            t.ID "ID",
            t.TARGET_ACTION "TARGET_ACTION",
            To_Char(t.TARGET_DATE, 'WW') "WEEK_NUM",
            w.WEEK_STARTS "WEEK_STARTS", 
            w.WEEK_ENDS "WEEK_ENDS"
        FROM
            a_table t
        INNER JOIN
            weeks w ON(To_Char(w.WEEK_NUM) = To_Char(t.TARGET_DATE, 'WW'))
    )
PIVOT
    (
        Count(WEEK_NUM)
        FOR WEEK_NUM IN(14 "W14", 15 "W15", 16 "W16")
    )
--  
--  R e s u l t
--  
--          ID        W14        W15        W16
--  ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
--         929          0          1          0 
--         366          0          0          1 
--         186          1          0          0
```

Regards...